# Extra newline in Jinja2 template

Tags: python, jinja2

Here is my Python code for generating the template

```
import jinja2

with open('test.j2', 'r') as f:
    template_body = f.read()

template = jinja2.Template(template_body)#, trim_blocks=True)
result = template.render(longest=len('staging'),
    envs=['devel', 'staging', 'prod'])

print(result)
```

The idea here is that I want to produce the follwing indented based on the longest string in the list.

```
devel   = 1
staging = 1
prod    = 1
```

I finally came up with a solution:

```
{% for env in envs -%}
{%- set padding = (longest - env|length + 1)|string %}
{% set f = "%-" + padding + "s" -%}
{{ env }}{{ f | format(' ',)}}= 1
{%- endfor %}
```

But I am getting

```
$ python test.py

devel   = 1
staging = 1
prod    = 1
```

There is an extra newline at the start of the output. Using Python's debugger, we can see the output:

```
$ python test.py
> /private/tmp/test.py(11)<module>()
-> print(result)
(Pdb) result
u'\ndevel   = 1\nstaging = 1\nprod    = 1'
```

Comment: Process the lines in python script and render them in jinja as resources. i.e. after processed, just iterate them to render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing a newline before each line by not suppressing the newline at the `set` line. On the other hand, you're suppressing a newline at the end in the `endfor` line. Thus, you get a newline before each line, but not after each line.

By changing the code like this, you get the reverse:

```
{% for env in envs -%}
{%- set padding = (longest - env|length + 1)|string -%}
{% set f = "%-" + padding + "s" -%}
{{ env }}{{ f | format(' ',)}}= 1
{% endfor %}
```

and `result` will be

```
u'devel   = 1\nstaging = 1\nprod    = 1\n'
```